# What is actual number of threads in a java process?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, memory-leaks

**Background**

- In the code below, "a" thread is created and started.
- The run method contains an infinite loop.
- In the loop the member variable "prod" is reassigned a newly configured object after every certain time interval.
- The configuration is based upon a json object which in turn in created using a config file

  ```
  public class Producer extends Thread {
      private long lastReadTime; 
      private long refreshInterval; 
      private String configFile; 
      private JSONObject configJson;
      private MyProducer prod; 

      public StdInProducer (String filename) throws IOException { 
         this.configFile = filename; 
         this.refreshConfig(); 
      } 

      public void refreshConfig() { 
          this.lastReadTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
          this.configJson = new JSONObject(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(this.configFile), "UTF-8"));
          this.refreshInterval = this.confJsonObj.optLong("refreshInterval", 86400);
          this.initializeProducer(configJson); 
      }

      private void initializeProducer(JSONObject confJsonObj) {
          //initialise producer using json object values
          this.prod = // new MyProducer obj with settings from json obj
      }

      public void run() {
           while(true) {
              long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              if(currentTime - this.lastReadTime > this.refreshInterval*1000) {
                  this.refreshConfig();    
              }
             // Rest of the code 
          }
     }
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String configFilename = args[0]; 
      Thread t = new Producer(configFilename);
      t.start();
  }
  ```

**Observations**

```
Thread.activeCount()
```

shows output as 2

```
ps -aefL | grep producer | grep -v "grep" | wc -l
```

shows 22 threads running initially when the program is kicked off.

```
ps -aefL | grep producer 
root     18498     1 18498  0   22 Jul22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/java -cp producer-1.0.jar stdin.producer.Producer stdinConfig.json                                                                     
root     18498     1 18499  0   22 Jul22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/java -cp producer-1.0.jar stdin.producer.Producer stdinConfig.json 
root     18498     1 18500  0   22 Jul22 ?        00:01:55 /usr/bin/java -cp producer-1.0.jar stdin.producer.Producer stdinConfig.json 
root     18498     1 18501  0   22 Jul22 ?        00:01:55 /usr/bin/java -cp producer-1.0.jar stdin.producer.Producer stdinConfig.json
```

(Showing only few of the rows due to space constraint)

The problem was observed when after around 2 months from initial running of program, number of threads on a box were observed to be ~70 (using ps command) and "top" showed the VIRT mem usage to be 12 GB.

**After restarting the program, 23rd thread got added to above list of
threads after one day (24 hrs), increasing virtual memory. So the problem is there, need to figure out why ?**

**Question**

How many threads does the program create ?

What is causing so many "threads" being shown by ps command ?

Why the number of thread is increasing with the time and hence the memory usage ?

Comment: Did you double check using something like JProfile or VisualVM, just to make sure your bash command is doing what you think it is ?

Comment: This is a Amazon EC2 box. I am now aware if I can install something like that to double check. I try to simulate similar thing on mac and check though

Comment: One of those threads is your main() thread, and one of them is the thread that your main thread created.  The rest are implementation details of the JVM.  Nothing in the Java Langauge Spec or the JVM Spec says how many of them there will be.  The exact number may be different in different JVMs, on different operating systems, and maybe at different times during the lifetime of your process.

Comment: Yes I am aware about the number 2. But number 22 or ~70 is what I am concerned about. Moreover, those ~70 have been generated on different days since the program was initially kicked of and some of them have not gone away for more than a month now.

Comment: JVisualm is the only way to ceck that out. Attach to living process and you will see what how many threads there are and what are they doing

Comment: Used JProfiler on mac laptop with similart smaller version of code. It shows appropriate number of threads matching the `Thread.activeCount()` call result but output of `ps M <pid>` shows 24 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was improper handling of library classes used. We used      `kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer` and we did not call a method `close()` before refreshing for configuration json file. That was leading to very unpredicted behaviour. We also removed threading part as just `main` thread was sufficient to perform the task instead of getting into concurrency overheads.